# MVC Razor to produce JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am really new to MVC and razor. Trying hard to get my hands in it.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);
        //   var albumImages = storeDB.AlbumImages.Find(id);
            //ICollection<AlbumImages> albumImages = getAlbumImages(id);
            //ViewBag.AlbumImages = albumImages;
            //if (albumImages.Count > 0)
            //    ViewBag.InitialImage = albumImages.ElementAt(0).Album800.ToString();

            return View(album);
        }

now on my cshtml in javascript I need, where in prodgallery 
in place of "Uploads/800/saree800.jpg" I need @ViewBag.Album800 
"Content/Uploads/380/saree380.jpg" I need @ViewBag.Album380 
"Content/Uploads/64/saree64.jpg" I need @ViewBag.Album64
```

In short this string should be dynamically generated from ViewBag data.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var prodGallery = jQblvg.parseJSON('{"prod_1":{"main":{"orig":"../../Content/Uploads/800/saree800.jpg","main":"../../Content/Uploads/380/saree380.jpg","thumb":"../../Content/Uploads/64/saree64.jpg","label":""},"gallery":{"item_0":{"orig":"../../Content/Uploads/800/saree800.jpg","main":"../../Content/Uploads/380/saree380.jpg","thumb":"../../Content/Uploads/64/saree64.jpg","label":""},"item_1":{"orig":"images/0001-1.jpg","main":"images/large/0001-1.jpg","thumb":"images/small/0001-1.jpg","label":""},"item_2":{"orig":"images/0001-5.jpg","main":"images/large/0001-5.jpg","thumb":"images/small/0001-5.jpg","label":""},"item_3":{"orig":"images/0001-3.jpg","main":"images/large/0001-3.jpg","thumb":"images/small/0001-3.jpg","label":""},"item_4":{"orig":"images/0001-4.jpg","main":"images/large/0001-4.jpg","thumb":"images/small/0001-4.jpg","label":""}},"type":"simple","video":false}}'),
</script>
```

Your help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
return Json(album, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of :

```
return View(album);
```

Hope will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Album800))
```

in a view to convert an object directly to JSON to use with JavaScript.